# Infinite While loop?

Tags: while-loop, infinite

```
function WhereIsMyLocation(){
    if (location.href == "http://www.gangwarsmobile.com/index.php?p=property"){
        setInterval(Property,400); clearInterval(Factory); GotoFactory();
    }

    if (location.href == "http://www.gangwarsmobile.com/index.php?p=industry"){
        setInterval(Factory,350); clearInterval(Property); GotoJob();
    }

    if (location.href == "http://www.gangwarsmobile.com/index.php?p=job"){
        CollectPaycheck(); GotoProperty();
    }
}

while(1){
    setTimeout(function(){WhereIsMyLocation()},20000)
}
```

So this is the updated code, For some reason this is causing my page to go unresponsive (Executed with TamperMonkey) obviously from the loop, I assume it's calling them timeout too fast as in it's just queuing up multiple calls? anyway to fix this?

Comment: If you need to do something like searching the location, what about using a callback that executes the same function again? it's actually quite similar to a long polling connection, you basically implement a function that call itself again on success, that would prevent the browser from freezing and having unexpected behaviors

Answer (score 0):

Its just while(i==0) not  While(i===0). try one less Equal.

Answer (score 0):

To produce an endless loop use:

```
while(1)
{...}
```

Comment: Updated the original question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MadPhysicist The reason my answer does not match the question is, because the the question was modified after I answered.